# How to make matlab block the shell in windows?

Tags: matlab, cygwin

I use win7 and matlab2012a. I want to write a shell script to test my matlab scripts with different parameters. I use cygwin for this task. For example, alpha is the parameter and the matlab script is getall.m. The matlab script will read parameters from txt file 'param.txt'.

```
#!/bin/sh
# List=`seq 0.1 0.01 1`
List=`seq 0.1 0.1 0.2`
for alpha in $List
do
    echo -ne "20\n61\n80\n1\n0.3\n${alpha}" > param.txt
    matlab -nodesktop -r "getall;quit;" #time consuming
done
```

My problem is that script "getall.m" is time consuming, so I'd like to exec it one at a time. But I found that matlab command returns immediately. So the upper script will start a lot of matlab instances at the same time. I also tried the matlab command in cmd, but nothing changes. In ubuntu, matlab blocks the shell by default.

My question is how to make the matlab command to block the shell in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the "right" way to do this - but I do have a hack for you:

Make the matlab script create a file called "matlabDone" in the /tmp directory just before quitting; your shell script can go around a loop looking for this file. Once it exists, you know matlab is finished. Delete the file, and go around the loop again.  Something like this:

```
List=`seq 0.1 0.1 0.2`
for alpha in $List
do
    echo -ne "20\n61\n80\n1\n0.3\n${alpha}" > param.txt
    matlab -nodesktop -r "getall;quit;" #time consuming
    while [ ! -e /tmp/matlabDone ]
    do
      sleep 1
    done
    rm /tmp/matlabDone
done
```

Then make the last line of your matlab script create the file `/tmp/matlabDone`...

As I said - it's a hack...

PS I am not 100% sure what functions are available in cygwin. If you can't use `sleep`, I saw an interesting post suggesting that `ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > /dev/null` (or equivalent ... depending on the version of ping you might need `-c 2 -i 1` to get "one second per ping, count two") can be an alternative to `sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `matlab -wait` command line switch on Windows that will make it block.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html

Comment: Thanks! "matlab -wait" works, and it's a more simpler way to do this.